# Android: Retrieve data of a specific user from a Firebase database in kotlin

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I want to retrieve my data from firebase after login but when successfully log in the app automatic closes

```
val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
        val userid = user!!.uid

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        reference = database.getReference("Profile")

        val fullnameTextView = findViewById<View>(R.id.fname) as TextView
        val lastnameTextView = findViewById<View>(R.id.lname) as TextView
        val emailTextView = findViewById<View>(R.id.ProfileEmail) as TextView
        val numberTextView = findViewById<View>(R.id.number) as TextView
        val addressTextView = findViewById<View>(R.id.address) as TextView
        reference.child(userid).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {

                val name = dataSnapshot.child("Fullname").value as String?
                val email = dataSnapshot.child("Email").value as String?
                val lname = dataSnapshot.child("Lastname").value as String?
                val cnumber = dataSnapshot.child("Contacts").value as String?
                val address = dataSnapshot.child("Address").value as String?

                fullnameTextView.text = name
                lastnameTextView.text = email
                emailTextView.text = lname
                numberTextView.text = cnumber
                addressTextView.text = address
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to give more information for another person to help you with the problem; either share your error report, piece of database you're reading from.
You can still go through the official documentantion and see what you're doing wrong...

[Firebase Documentantion](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)